# template which takes a pack of type T

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I have the following minimal code fragment which compiles and executes as expected:

```
template < class T, T... Chrs>
struct mystring
{
    static auto c_str()
    {
        static char str[] = {Chrs..., 0};
        return str;
    }

};

template <class T, T... Chrs>
auto operator""_t()
{
    return mystring<T, Chrs...>();
}

int main()
{
    auto x = "Hallo"_t ;
    std::cout << x.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Question:

Is it possible to write the template `mystring` in a way that it excepts:

```
 auto x = mystring<'a','b','c'>();
```

but also

```
 auto x = mystring< 1,2,3> ();
```

or any other type.

I have no idea how to write something like ( pseudo code ):

```
template < T ... Chrs> // how to define T here?
struct mystring
{ }
```

Also the following is not allowed:

```
template <typename T, T ...Chrs >
struct mystring<T...Chrs> {};
```

Comment: Why not make `Chrs` a `char...` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you're doing it right now. Except instead of using `T`, where `T` is a template parameter, just use `char` directly:

```
template <char... Chrs>
struct mystring
{
    /* rest as before */
};
```

Of course this now only works for `char` and not `wchar_t` (but then again, so does the original)

---

You can generalize this by writing something like:

```
template <class T, T... Vals>
struct array { ... };

template <char... Chrs>
using mystring  = array<char, Chrs...>;
```

In C++17, we'll have `template auto` which would let you write:

```
template <auto... Vals>
struct array { /* .. */ };
```

and then it's up to you to verify that all the `Vals` are the same type. Perhaps via:

```
template <auto Val, decltype(Val)... Vals>
struct array { /* .. */ };
```

Comment: Ok, in case of a known type you are right. My question is imprecise. It should fit to any parameter type like `mystring<1,2,3>` and others. I updated my question. Sorry for my unclear wording.

Comment: What is `mystring<1,2,3>().c_str()` supposed to be ? `"123"` ?

Comment: @Klaus That's not much of a string at that point. But added a general array bit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to c++17. So in conclusion it can not be done with c++14, right?

Comment: @Nelxiost: Sorry, you are right. The use case is a copy of a working example and with `int` it makes no sense at all. But it should be possible to find use cases for the requested template definition problem. My question goes to the template syntax for a parameter pack of an unknown type.